# Что происходит в данной строке?

Tags: java

Допустим, есть строка:

```
lr.eval_string("{MQ_HOST}")
```

Что в данном случае передаётся в функцию как параметр? Почему в {}?

Comment: Предположительно, судя по названию в этой функции идет запуск кода 
 формата JSON. Насчет фигурных скобок, если я все таки прав, то почитай про JSON.

Answer (score 3):

В метод передается строка `{MQ_HOST}`. Фигурные скобки – это часть строки.